# Rails 3 sendgrid support failing to send emails... tried everything I found on the web... : P

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, actionmailer, sendgrid

So I've got a sendgrid account, and I'm trying to get Rails 3 to send emails through it... Here are some of my settings:

```
#development.rb

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "smtp.sendgrid.net" }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
        :port => '587',
        :domain => "place.com",
        :authentication => :plain,
        :user_name => "me@place.com",
        :password => "password",
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I'm using Ubuntu Mint, and `sendmail` can send emails, I can also telnet into `smtp.sendgrid.net 587` successfully.

I've tried all kinds of other random combinations of things to no avail.  Anyone got any more ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any kind of error raised by the ruby code? If not, have you tried logging into the Sendgrid panel and check the status of the emails? If they were bounced, there should be an explanation there of why they were not sent. Also, the config.action_mailer.default_url_options parameter is used to generate links to your site in the emails you sent, so it should probably be 'place.com' not smtp.sendgrid.net.

Comment: Does your code work as expected when using an SMTP server other than SendGrid's?

Comment: have you tried setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your postfix configuration file to send emails via a relayhost.  I'm guessing you're ISP is blocking your outgoing port 25.  Check out the link below:

http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=postfix

Comment: Postfix has nothing to do with it, and even if the ISP is blocking port 25, the mailer configuration specifies port 587.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your problem is the same as mine, but I just figured out how to make SendGrid work after wasting half a day on it. Disclaimer: I am VERY new to RoR - just started playing with simple apps two-three days ago. My problem seemed to be something that only a newbie can encounter...

Anyway, without further ado, this is what happened. I added the recommended lines to environment.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => "your_username",
    :password => "your_password",
    :domain => "yourdomain.com",
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Then I tried to send an email and got a strange behavior:

- The development log said it was sent
- Well, SendGrid didn't even try to send it
- When I tried to go into "rails console", I got an error saying "undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)"

It turned out that I have to enclose the config.* stuff in the following:

```
YourApplicationName::Application.configure do
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
end
```

It worked like magic after that. Hope this helps, if not you, some other hapless newbie at least...

EDIT:

Well, I spoke too early. With the modifications above I am able to send and receive the email ONLY if invoking the Emailer from the rails console. If I call it from within the app, the development log says the email was sent, but I don't receive it... What is the difference between the console environment and the app? Note that when I follow the postfix instructions on SendGrid and start postfix, the email gets send from the app alright.

If you have found the answer to your problem, please post it here...

Comment: If you're sending in the development environment, you might have `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false`. it should be `true` if you want to send mail... check your `config/environments/development.rb` file.  I never did solve this problem, it worked just fine in another project, so I dunno what was wrong with this one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm glad it worked for your other project. :) perform_deliveries is set to true in my development.rb file. Moreover, I'm explicitly running 'rails console development', so the email is sent fine from the development environment in that case. It's just that when my Emailer.send_mail(user, text).deliver method is called through the web flow, the email never gets to SendGrid, even though the development.log says it was sent. Once I get some clue how to debug rails, I may discover what part of the "magic" is broken...

Comment: there are a bunch of ways to debug rails: running `rails s -u` and putting `debugger` in your code will open up a console once it gets to that point (see the default generated README in your project root folder), or printing stuff to your logs with logger.debug "stuff I want to print", and the NetBeans IDE has a debugger that works with rails, and is pretty cool if you're familiar with IDE debuggers.  There's also the code buddy gem, which I like, to inspect your trace after an error happens... as far as this mailer thing goes, the IDE debugger might give you some clues...

Comment: So, I think I found the problem... I restarted the rails server in debug mode and emails magically started appearing. I guess the server needed restarting to pick up the config changes or something. The emails were sent successfully from the console because the configs were loaded every time I ran 'rails console'. I'm sure this would have been obvious to an experienced RoR programmer, but I'm still not clear what are the dependencies between the rails server and the code I'm modifying. Maybe that was your issue at the time too.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, restarting the server is usually the first thing I do when I think something should work and it's not.  No worries, it's in the past.  : )